# Some (but not all) static content proxied by nginx loads successfully

Tags: windows, nginx, ssl, node.js

I have nginx setup on my windows machine as a reverse proxy, listening on 443 over ssl. When I hit a particular url, it is supposed to serve a node js web application that I have running locally. It hits the application successfully - however, it loads some but not all of the web application's static content. *Which* files aren't loaded varies each time.

There are several css and JavaScript files that are supposed to be loaded. When I check the network tab of the Developer Tools in Chrome, it shows two of the files pending indefinitely, while the others have been loaded fine. Which two files varies *each* time.

[image: Developer Tools]

This is my nginx.conf (I have substituted the actual urls for privacy's sake.):

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  0;
    client_max_body_size 1024M;

    proxy_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_buffers 4 256k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;

    # time is in seconds
    proxy_connect_timeout       1000;
    proxy_send_timeout          1000;
    proxy_read_timeout          1000;
    send_timeout                1000;

    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    Host $host;

    server {
        listen 443;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key cert.key;
        ssl_verify_client optional_no_ca;
        server_name  v-mysite.com;

        error_log logs/error.log debug;

        location / {
            proxy_pass https://pm-mysite.com:4434;
        }

        location /mja/ {
            proxy_pass https://pm-mysite.com:4433;
        }

        location /mja/cassette.axd/ {
            proxy_pass https://pm-mysite.com:4433/cassette.axd/;
        }

        location /mja/content/ {
            proxy_pass https://pm-mysite.com:4433/Content/;
        }

        location /api/myappcenter/ {
            proxy_pass https://pm-mysite.com:4333/;
       }

        location /api/documentation/myappcenter {
            proxy_pass https://qa-mysite.com:4433/documentation;
        }

        location /api/person/match {
            proxy_pass https://anothersite.com:43443/match;
        }

        location /api/sms/ {
            proxy_pass https://anothersite.com:44443/;
        }

        location /myapp/content/ {
            proxy_pass http://pm-mysite.com:5000/;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        }

        location /api/myapp/ {
            proxy_pass http://pm-mysite.com:5000/api/;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
        }

        location ~* ^/(?!api)(?<alias>\w+)/myapp/index/(?<path>.*)$ {
            proxy_pass http://pm-mysite.com:5000/$path;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Alias $alias;
        }
    }
}
```

I have set the nginx error log to debug, and included a (hopefully) relevant piece of it here. There might be an ssl read error of some sort occurring.

```
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 http process request line
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 http request line: "GET /myapp/content/js/resources.en.js HTTP/1.1"
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 http uri: "/myapp/content/js/resources.en.js"
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 http args: ""
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 http exten: "js"
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 http process request header line
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 http header: "Host: v-mysite.com"
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 http header: "Connection: keep-alive"
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 http header: "Cache-Control: max-age=0"
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 http header: "Accept: */*"
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 http header: "If-None-Match: "1d18a93e19632ee""
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 http header: "If-Modified-Since: Wed, 30 Mar 2016 14:53:12 GMT"
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 http header: "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.110 Safari/537.36"
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 http header: "Referer: https://v-mysite.com/myapp/Index/AuLKHOtasdfasdfzGkmXOaUkAasdfL2uWQ"
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 http header: "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch"
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 http header: "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,de;q=0.6"
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 http alloc large header buffer
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 malloc: 0237BEE0:8192
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 http large header alloc: 0237BEE0 8192
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 http large header copy: 493
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 SSL_read: 3577
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 SSL_read: -1
[debug] 9684#11312: *278 SSL_get_error: 2
```

I'm pretty new to nginx, to please go easy on me. :)

Comment: With something like this it's best to post a link to your website. People often obfuscate for no good reason. Also, you have a very minimal SSH configuration, have a look at the sample config files downloadable from this tutorial I wrote - mid way down the page https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-pt1-introduction-configuration-downloads/

Comment: @Tim it's not a public site, I'm sorry.

Comment: Nginx on windows should not be used for any production purposes at first place. http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html

Comment: @AlexeyTen its only being used for development purposes, but the site url's are similar to our production urls.

Comment: I would just use virtual container with linux server.